# Использование консоли в винде

Tags: linux, windows, cmd

Есть ли какая-нибудь симуляция, или что-то вроде этого, которая позволяет использовать консольные команды линукса на винде?
Просто не хочется поверх основной оси (Windows 10) ставить еще одну, а использовать консольку винды я не очень умею, да и не люблю...

Comment: [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) - встроенная поддержка окружения линукса доступна на Windows 10.

Comment: @AlexKrass, я что-то слышал об этой подсистеме, но с ее помощи вроде нельзя запускать приложения, из системы винды?

Comment: А и как он будет скачивать какие-нибудь утилиты, допустим npm, он будет работать на винде, или он будет работать лишь из под этой подсистемы линукса?

Comment: Там достаточно тесная интеграция и я использовал этот инструмент немного, в основном поиграться. Многое о ней не скажу, но попробуйте, проблем быть не должно. Скорее всего зависит от способа запуска npm - запустите вы линуксовый исполняемый файл или укажете путь явно к windows .exe файлу.

Comment: @AlexKrass, Ладно, попробую. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если только поиграться на черьезные задачи не подойдет 100 %

Comment: Так в вопросе: "_позволяет использовать консольные команды линукса на винде_", а так в комментарии:  "_с ее помощи вроде нельзя запускать приложения, из системы винды_". Вам не кажется, что несколько отличается? Если кто-то даст ответ, то на вопрос, не на комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых нужно уточнить, что это две различные ОС и о ни какой совместимости при запуске ПО вы не добьетесь.

Как мне показалось из контекста вас заинтересует проект [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)
Также от себя хочу добавить что под виндой удобно пользоваться https://chocolatey.org (если вы хотите испытать unix подход).

Но современная тенденция говорит, что сообщество движется в сторону WSL, о котором писалось выше.

Comment: Да, это именно то, что я и искал. Просто работая с линуксом, я понял, что куда удобнее работать с консолью (скачивать различные утилиты, запускать приложения и т.д. и т.п.), и вот chocatey это именно то, что мне надо, спасибо. Как домой приду обязательно протестирую!